# Chart.js wont display normal chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, chart.js

I have an issue with Chart.js. when I had my data inside Javascript, it showed the graph just fine. Now I would like to make it ready from JSON. but for some reason its reading wrong.
I followed the example from their website and it suppose to show me this
[image]
but instead I get to see this
[image]
Notice the 3 first weeks have data on them. when I hover over them it shows me the data. here is the JSON

```
[{
"label": "Net Comp",
"color": "#F02626",
"data": [520, 600, 850, 900, 300]
},
{
"label": "AnalyzerHR",
"color": "#26F041",
"data": [ [6, 300], [7, 400], [8, 550], [9, 750], [10, 200] ]
},
{
"label": "Question Right",
"color": "#20AEFA",
"data": [ [6, 200], [7, 150], [8, 380], [9, 400], [10, 100] ]
```

}]
so the 3 data are packed as array and they are display on the 3 first labels.
So when I hover it shows to me `520, 600, 850, 900, 300` .
And this is wrong because each value in data should be over 1 of the weeks. not the 1 data in the 1st week only.
here is my Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON('data.json', function(data){
    console.log(data);

    var myData = (data);

    Array.prototype.mapProperty = function(property) {
    return this.map(function (obj) {
      return obj[property];
     });
    };
    lineChartData = {
        labels : [["Week 47"],[7,"week 48"], [8,"Week 49"], [9,"Week 50"], [10,"Week 51"], [11,"Week 52"]],
        datasets: [
        {        
        label: "Test",
        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data : myData.mapProperty("data"),

    }]};
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myLineChart").getContext("2d");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData);

});
```

});

How can I set each data value to a different week?
I cant see any mistake in my code (I know there is somewhere). Chartjs is able to read JSON and display it, but in the wrong place

Thank you in advance

**Edited**
I found where the problem is but I can't find the way to fix it. I made some testings and it seems that while in Javascript Chartjs is reading the data as `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`. But when I call it, it gets all 3 objects. and it wont accept when I write something like `data : chartjsData.data` inside the datasets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem, I found the Solution. Obviously it was right in front of my eyes.

I ve changed the

```
var myData = (data);

Array.prototype.mapProperty = function(property) {
return this.map(function (obj) {
  return obj[property];
});
```

with a bit different code ->

```
var chartjsData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    chartjsData.push(data[i].data); 
};
```

But the main reason why the data was printed incorrect, it was because of the way I set the `datasets` inside `lineChartData`.  I only used ONE datasets. Which this equals of course into 1 data. so I just added all 3 json.data inside datasets (data). Each datasets (data) is 1 line. so I got 3 response in one line. So the obvious thing to do is

Create more datasets (data). Here is my solution:

```
datasets: [
    {        
        label: "Test",
        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data : chartjsData[0]
    },{
        label: "Test2",
        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data : chartjsData[1]
    },{
        label: "Test3",
        fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data : chartjsData[2]
    }
]
```

I hope this will help some people that just starting with Chartjs. Its a great library.